# StudioPress: add meta tag to every page

Tags: php, headers, genesis-theme-framework

I need to add this meta tag to every page in my site.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

I found this PHP function on github

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wsm_keep_ie_modern' ); 
function wsm_keep_ie_modern( $headers ) {
   if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) && ( strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE' ) !== false ) ) {
           $headers['X-UA-Compatible'] = 'IE=edge';
    }
    return $headers;   
}
```

I tried adding it to my child theme functions.php file by downloading the file with FTP, adding this chunk to the end in a text editor, and then uploading it (via FileZilla).

This did not work, and viewing the HTML source files in the debugger showed that the meta tag did not appear. I don't have access to the individual HTML pages otherwise I would just add it manually.

And yes, I know IE sucks times a million, and its older versions are no longer supported, but I'm under strict orders to make it work. Also, I was just thrown into this wordpress mess yesterday having never done web development before (some coding background though). So explain it like I'm five please.

TL;DR: How do I add the same meta tag to every page on my StudioPress website? Also, from my understanding it needs to be in the header and as near the top as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function should take care for the input into the head of each page/post as asked.

> Please make a copy of `functions.php` before adding following code.
> Adjust to your own preferences if needed.

```
/**
 * Add meta to head
 *
 * Read more {@link https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head} 
 * @version Wordpress 4.8
 */
function wpse272951_wsm_keep_ie_modern() 
{
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\"/> \n";
} 
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse272951_wsm_keep_ie_modern' );
```

PS, it should not be added into the header as mentioned by you but into the head of a page *between `<head> </head>`* (which will be done by this function automatically).

Comment: Thanks so much! Does it matter where in the functions.php file I put it?

Comment: It is not important where in the `functions.php` as long it comes after the opening `<?php`. Cheers. *(Please select the 'accept answer' marker so others will also know the function works and the topic is closed)*

Comment: The tag appears, but it's far down in the head section, so by the time this tag is reached, the browser has already decided on a particular mode. I need to be able to put it right at the top (before the title, like the charset tag)